# Is there a way to force iOS to *not* deep/universal link from the browser?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am having a real hard time finding an answer to this. I know that the app manifest itself can exclude links, but I have an active bug that is affecting users and updating the app is not a fix for current users unfortunately.

The issue is that on our mobile site, we have a flow where it redirects to another domain, an then redirects back. On that 2nd redirect back, if our app is installed on the device, the app will briefly open before switching back to the browser. When this happens, the page breaks (as the 2nd redirect is actually a form submission (a POST) and the app can't forward that POST on.

Is there a way we can add a header or a param or something to tell iOS to *not* try a deep/universal link? Something to just use safari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not with headers

Unfortunately, the device will only make a request to the Universal Link if it does not find a matching AASA file on your device. It will perform a handoff to your app which is done on the local OS with no requests. Therefore, there is no way to check the headers of the request if the device recognizes it as a Universal link.

### Same domain fix

The only case in which Universal Link will use the browser if the app is installed is when a is already on the Universal Link domain when they click the universal link.

Example: If a user is on `example.com` on Safair, they have an AASA on their device that has `applinks:example.com`, and they click a link that redirects them to `example.com/item123`, they will not open the app.

In your case, you leave the domain and come back. Your best bet is to figure out a way to redirect the user while keeping them on the same domain. I know that probably doesn't help a ton, but that's your best bet.

Comment: That's really damn unfortunate, but thank you for the explanation. Bug will remain in place until people upgrade their app, and even then there'll be people who don't update who experience the bug ;-;